# How to send the value of the e-mail address with Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a form area like the one below, and if you have an e-mail address, I want a value for that email address sent. But I'm getting an error that there's no value.

I want the value of the e-mail to be e-mailed.

undefined method `value' for nil:NilClass

```
Extracted source (around line #71):

 rad_check = params[:emailaddress]
 **data = RadCheck.find_by(emailaddress: params[:emailaddress]).value**
 RadCheckMailer.rad_check_forgot(rad_check, data).deliver
```

rad_checks_controller.rb

```
def forgot    
  rad_check = params[:emailaddress]
  data = RadCheck.find_by(emailaddress: params[:emailaddress]).value
  RadCheckMailer.rad_check_forgot(rad_check, data).deliver           
end
```

rad_check_mailer.rb

```
class RadCheckMailer < ApplicationMailer
    default :from => "test@domain.com"

    def rad_check_forgot(emailaddress, data)
        @rad_check_data = data
        mail(:to => emailaddress, :subject => "Forgot")
    end
end
```

rad_check_forgot.text.erb

```
<%= @rad_check_data %>

Tanks!
```

forgot.html.erb

```
    <%= form_tag 'forgot' do %>

      <div id="error" class="middle-box text-left loginscreen">
        <%# Error Messages display here! %>
      </div>



      <div class="form-group">
        <%= text_field_tag  "emailaddress" %>
      </div>



      <div class="form-group">              
        <%= submit_tag "submit"%>
      </div>
    </div>
    <% end %>
    <p class="m-t"> <small>Corperation &copy; 2019</small> </p>
  <div>
</div>
```

RadCheck Table

```
class CreateRadChecks < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def change
    create_table :rad_checks, force: :cascade do |t|

      t.string :value,        :limit => 253, default: "",   null: false      
      t.string :emailaddress


      t.timestamps

    end
    add_index(:rad_checks, :emailaddress, {:name=>:emailaddress, :length=>{:emailaddress=>32}, :using=>"btree"})
  end
end
```

Comment: Are you using strong params or does the record exist in the database?

Comment: The registry has available emailaddress: test@test.com value: test data.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can't take the column name as "value", it's a reserved keyword. please check it once.

Update: Are you getting `params[:emailaddress]` value? If it is getting then it should be present in  RadCheck table. When you use `find_by` method it will return `nil` if condition is false. So when we get `nil` then there is no scope for nil.vlaue. Thats way your getting that error.

Please check value of params[:emailaddress] existed in table records or not. Try below code.

```
if params[:emailaddress]
  rad_check = params[:emailaddress]
  data = RadCheck.find_by(emailaddress: params[:emailaddress]).value
  RadCheckMailer.rad_check_forgot(rad_check, data).deliver 
end
```

Comment: you're right, I changed it, but the problem is the same... 'data = RadCheck.find_by(emailaddress: params[:emailaddress]).radvalue'

Comment: When I type my email address in "test@test.com" instead of params[:emailaddress], the email comes and works.

Comment: first byebug the params in controller like `data = RadCheck.find_by(emailaddress: params[:emailaddress])` . It is return value then above code should be work, otherwise it will give following Nil class error

Comment: I get this error when I enter the http://localhost:3000/rad_checks/forgot form address. There's data in the RadCheck table test@test.com and the radvalue column, but when I try to enter the link above, the form doesn't come in front of me and I get the error. Everything works when I replace it with "email address" instead of params[:emailaddress].

Comment: first byebug the params in controller like data = RadCheck.find_by(emailaddress: params[:emailaddress]) . It is return value then above code should be work, otherwise it will give following Nil class error..... I've done some experiments with what you've written. But I didn't succeed, can you give me a sample code?

Comment: Yes you will get error when you try `localhost:3000/rad_checks/forgot` . why because directly your calling `forget` without rendering the `form`. So controller not getting params initially. Try my updated answer it should be work.

Comment: Use this code `if params[:emailaddress]
  drad_check = params[:emailaddress]
  data = RadCheck.find_by(emailaddress: params[:emailaddress]).value
  RadCheckMailer.rad_check_forgot(rad_check, data).deliver 
end`

Comment: Unfortunately, none of it worked. This code worked until it stopped and restarted the "rails s" command. data = RadCheck.find_by (emailaddress: params[:emailaddress]).value if RadCheck.find_by (emailaddress: params[:emailaddress])

The last code you sent "if params[:emailaddress]" form opens, i send, but the same error "value nil"

Comment: Then you can create two actions in controller. one is for to call form and another one is for to get information from the form then that will be work for you

Comment: I actually did a similar experiment, but it didn't happen. Would you share a sample code if I asked you to?

Comment: My problem persists. Can you help with the solution?